# Excel 2007 MedianIfs()

Tags: excel, statistics, excel-2007, median

I want to calculate some statistics.

In order to calculate the average of certain values of a column, I use AverageIfs().

Now I want to calculate the median for the same values. But there is no MedianIfs() function.

Is there a simple solution to calculate the median for values that hold certain conditions (2 conditions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this response on an [Excel board](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-worksheet-functions/649086-medianifs-possible.html)